# how to store accent marks over characters in my database

Tags: mysql, collation

I'm storing responses from the google geocoded into my database.

One such response has an accent mark over the o.  The town is Rincon.  (I would put the accent mark here to show you, but I don't know how.)

When the response is stored into my mySQL database it looks like this: RincÃ³n

I realize that this has to do with Collation, but I'm nervous about making changes to the database because I have so much data in there.  The Collation that is currently applied to this field is utf8_general_ci.

Can anyone advise:
1) Is utf8_general_ci the correct Collation.
2) Do I need to somehow specify this Collation in my ajax request?

Thank you....

Comment: What programming language are you using? By example, if it is PHP, you coud mb_convert_encoding your data before storing into de DB

Comment: I am using PHP.  What args would I want to use with  mb_convert_encoding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UTF-8 is (generally) a “safe” encoding for any character set in the world. (Not always the most efficient, and there are some arguments to be made that Unicode under-represents the CJK scripts with its “unified han” model, but moving on…)

However, it's likely that your interface program(s) are not translating to/from UTF-8 properly. For example, ó => Ã³ looks like the UTF-8 data (where one character can be spread across a varying number of bytes) is being presented to you using a single-byte European encoding, like ISO-8859-15 or MS-CP-1451 or similar.

You are *probably* storing the data correctly, but *loading* it incorrectly. If you're just using the `mysql` terminal program or similar, make sure that your terminal is set to use UTF-8 (on a Unix/Linux system, `locale` should probably be something ending in `.utf8`, e.g. mine has `LANG=en_US.utf8`)

If you're pulling data using a GUI tool or similar, check its Settings/Preferences panel for the character set.

If you're getting the mistranslated characters back into an application you've written, look at your language's tools for setting the locale. (Perhaps, the `INSERT` routines have it right, but the `SELECT` routines have it wrong?)

And, if this is being sent to the Web, make sure your (XML|HTML|XHTML) files have `charset=utf8` declared in the appropriate place(s), *or* translate back from UTF-8 to the character set of your document (if possible) using something like `iconv` when inserting text from the database. (Most non-Unicode character sets can only represent a subset of Unicode, of course; e.g. the ISO-8859-15 set does a decent job at covering European languages, but has no support for Cyrillic, Arabic, or CJK writing systems, so it's possible to fail to translate a character.) In Perl, you can use pass arguments to `open` or use `binmode` to set up a transparent character set translation layer on a "filehandle" stream.

Comment: when I use a javascript alert to show the geocode's return value I see "Rincón, PR, 00602".  I also see this same value written into a div within my web app.  Then when I reload the web app (which forces the web app to fetch the data from my database) it's displayed as RincÃ³n, PR, 00602.  When I use phpMyAdmin to view the stored value I also see RincÃ³n, PR, 00602.  Does this information help?

Comment: Check the document content type (e.g. `text/html; charset=utf8`) in your HTTP or HTML headers; (HTTP `Content-Type:` or HTML `meta http-equiv` `Content-Type`); if those are already UTF8, you might need to make sure that the locale your PHP script runs under is set to UTF8 and/or use `iconv` in your script to translate the character encoding. Unfortunately, I'm not a user (nor a fan :-( ) of PHP, so I'm not 100% sure where to look for it. But, it could be getting corrupted when you read it in from `$_POST` or so forth.

Comment: Per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332781/phpmyadmin-displays-japanese-characters-as-a-bunch-of-question-marks-even-if-i-s you might try `mysqli_set_charset ( $mysqli,'utf8');` or `$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");`

Comment: adding this to my html file fixed the issue: <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />  Thank you.